# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a mis objetos y Arraylist usando retrofit?

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit

estoy haciendo una app API REST con método GET.

quiero que se imprima en un Texteview o RecycreView toda esta información en la APP.

[image: JSON en POSTMAN]

Pero me encuentro con que se extiende "rowset" y ahí es cuándo se me complica.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces creé dos clases, con sus getters, setters y constructores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

subo los códigos de las dos clases.

```
public class Datareq {

@SerializedName("tableId")
private String tableId;


//se creó una clase para llamar a los atributos de este objeto en "MoreRowsets"
@SerializedName("rowset")
private MoreRowsets rowsets;

@SerializedName("records")
private Integer records;


@SerializedName("moreRecords")
private Boolean moreRecords;

//constructors
public Datareq(String tableId, MoreRowsets rowsets, Integer records, Boolean moreRecords) {
    this.tableId = tableId;
    this.rowsets = rowsets;
    this.records = records;
    this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
}

//getters y setters
public String getTableId() {
    return tableId;
}

public void setTableId(String tableId) {
    this.tableId = tableId;
}

public MoreRowsets getRowsets() {
    return rowsets;
}

public void setRowsets(MoreRowsets rowsets) {
    this.rowsets = rowsets;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public Boolean getMoreRecords() {
    return moreRecords;
}

public void setMoreRecords(Boolean moreRecords) {
    this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
}
```

la clase para el Rowset

```
public class MoreRowsets {

@SerializedName("NRO_INTERNO")
private String nroInterno;

@SerializedName("TIPO_INTERNO")
private String tipoInterno;

@SerializedName("FECHA_FACTURA")
private String fechaFactura;

@SerializedName("MONTO")
private Integer monto;

@SerializedName("FECHA_VENCIMIENTO")
private String fechaVencimiento;

@SerializedName("NRO_LEGAL")
private String nroLegal;


//getters

public String getNroInterno() {
    return nroInterno;
}

public String getTipoInterno() {
    return tipoInterno;
}

public String getFechaFactura() {
    return fechaFactura;
}

public Integer getMonto() {
    return monto;
}

public String getFechaVencimiento() {
    return fechaVencimiento;
}

public String getNroLegal() {
    return nroLegal;
}


//constructors


public MoreRowsets(String nroInterno, String tipoInterno, String fechaFactura, Integer monto, String fechaVencimiento, String nroLegal) {
    this.nroInterno = nroInterno;
    this.tipoInterno = tipoInterno;
    this.fechaFactura = fechaFactura;
    this.monto = monto;
    this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
    this.nroLegal = nroLegal;
}
```

}

la interface

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@Headers({"Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept:application/json",
        "Cookie:JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743",
        "Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" })
@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH?Cliente=80003")

Call<Datareq> getDatareqs( @Query("Cliente") String cliente);
```

}

y mi mainActivity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       
       
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        

}


   }
```

sé que tengo que empezar el llamado con una Call debajo del **retrofit**, pero no pude seguir.

En resumen, quiero que el JSON  QUE aparece en el POSTMAN aparezca en la app, pero

¡muchas gracias!

Solución

Añadí

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@Headers({"Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept:application/json",
        "Cookie:JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743",
        "Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx" })
@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH?Cliente=80003")

Call<Map<String,Datareq>>getDatareqs(@Query("Cliente") String cliente);
```

}

y en main activity debajo de retrofit haré el llamado

```
  Call<Map<String,Datareq>>call = JsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, Datareq>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, Datareq>> call, Response<Map<String, Datareq>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                Map<String,Datareq> datareqMap = response.body();
                for (Datareq dataraq : datareqMap ) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "tableId: " + dataraq.getTableId() + "\n";
                    content += "rowset: " + dataraq.getRecords() + "\n";
                    content += "records: " + dataraq.getRecords() + "\n";
                    content += "moreRecords: " + dataraq.getMoreRecords() + "\n";

                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, Datareq>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

lo que me quedaría es llamar a la lista de "rowset". Avancé un montón gracias a la ayuda de la comunidad.

lo que noté es que me pide que creé un metodo para "getDatareqs"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes un problema con la construcción del objeto del JSON, "rowset" es una colección de MoreRowsets.class
El atributo en tu clase podría ser una lista.

```
@SerializedName("rowset")
private List<MoreRowsets> rowsets;
```

Ademas, fijate la estructura del objeto principal de la respuesta del endpoint:

```
"03_011A_DATAREQ" : {
"tableId" : "F03B11",
"rowset": [...],
"records" 56,
"moreRecords" false
}
```

Lo que te devuelve la llamada es un Mapa de String - Datareq:
Por lo que en tu interfaz JsonPlaceHolderApi la llamada devolvería

```
Call<Map<String,Datareq>> getDatareqs( @Query("Cliente") String cliente);
```

O tambien podes crear una clase muy simple "DatareqResponse"

```
Call<DatareqResponse> getDatareqs( @Query("Cliente") String cliente);



public class DatareqResponse {
private Map<String,Datareq> datareqMap;
}
```

Con eso te debería funcionar. Luego no sé como es tu vista pero para mostrar la información vas a tener que recorrer las Colecciones. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por contestarme.

justo encontré un ejemplo de construcción con tu tip. lo voy a probar! entonces la clase "MoreRowsets" lo dejo tal cualesta? y con ese llamado de list, haria su funcion?

Comment: y en mi interface solamente con hacer este llamado, cumpliria la funcion de la List?

@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH?Cliente=80003")

    Call<Datareq> getDatareqs( @Query("Cliente") String cliente);

Comment: Ahi actualice mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por guiarme! ahí modifiqué la interface 

`Call<Map<String,Datareq>>getDatareqs(@Query("Cliente") String cliente);`

Comment: @Ornerlla D subí mis avances gracias a tu aporte! solo me quedan los pasos finaes creo yo. podrias ver lo último que agregué en el post, mas detallada? desde ya te agradezco mucho

Comment: Podrias compartir el link del repo para ver el codigo completo?

Comment: Tenes que llamar a jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003);
Si llamas a JsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs(80003); estarías hablando de un método estatico en la clase, vos necesitas usar el que acabas de crear haciendo retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);